# Segmented textbox in WPF

Tags: wpf, textbox, wpf-controls

Is anyone aware of a free or commercial WPF control that would do something like this:

[image]

X character per box, and auto-tabbing to the next box as you complete each box?  Similar to the way that license keys are entered for Microsoft products.

I don't think it would be particularly hard to do from scratch, but I'd like to avoid reinventing the wheel if a good example of this already exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WPF provides all you need except auto-tabbing to the next control.  A behavior can provide that functionality and the result looks like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:KeyTextCollection x:Key="keys"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{StaticResource keys}" Focusable="False">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="AliceBlue"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" Margin="5" MaxLength="4" Width="40">
                        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <local:TextBoxBehavior AutoTab="True" SelectOnFocus="True"/>
                        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    </TextBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Here are the KeyText and KeyTextCollection classes (adjust to taste):

```
class KeyText
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

class KeyTextCollection : List<KeyText>
{
    public KeyTextCollection()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) Add(new KeyText { Text = "" });
    }
}
```

And here is the behavior that implements auto-tab and select-on-focus:

```
public class TextBoxBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    public bool SelectOnFocus
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(SelectOnFocusProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectOnFocusProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectOnFocusProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectOnFocus", typeof(bool), typeof(TextBoxBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));

    public bool AutoTab
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(AutoTabProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AutoTabProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AutoTabProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("AutoTab", typeof(bool), typeof(TextBoxBase), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.PreviewGotKeyboardFocus += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (SelectOnFocus)
            {
                Action action = () => AssociatedObject.SelectAll();
                AssociatedObject.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action, DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
            }
        };
        AssociatedObject.TextChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (AutoTab)
            {
                if (AssociatedObject.Text.Length == AssociatedObject.MaxLength &&
                    AssociatedObject.SelectionStart == AssociatedObject.MaxLength)
                {
                    AssociatedObject.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

If you are not familiar with behaviors, Install the Expression Blend 4 SDK and add this namespaces:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

and add `System.Windows.Interactivity` to your project.

Comment: This uses some deprecated packages, follow these steps to upgrade: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/open-sourcing-xaml-behaviors-for-wpf/#:~:text=on%20.NET%20Core.-,Steps%20to%20migrate%3A,-Remove%20reference%20to