# How to implement PIN entry with cell for each digit using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

What's a good approach for creating a dialog for entering an 8 digit pin number. It needs to work similar to a TextBox, but each digit should be shown in its own box. Is there an existing control that will do this? Is it possible to visually style a TextBox so that it looks like a series of boxes, one for each digit? Should a custom control be created with a TextBox for each digit with lots of event handling so that typing will move focus between cells and so that clipboard paste will distribute characters between each cell?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772033/segmented-textbox-in-wpf

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, using a `TextBox` is probably the best way to complete this. What you want is
`<TextBox MaxLength="1"/>`

This would allow only one character input per box. Simply line up x-amount of boxes for the length of the pin.

You could also do some work in the code-behind to automatically advance to the next when one had been filled so it is a smooth experience. I also suggest checking to make sure each `TextBox` only receives numeric values (`try { int.Parse(textbox.Text.ToString()) } catch (Exception) { // Not a number! }`) because there isn't a way to do that in XAML.

There are numeric input controls but those generally include buttons for the mouse and don't have the same feel.

Additionally as **rbdeenk** suggested you can use tab-index to allow the user to tab-through (though it might be smoother to have it auto-advance from the code-behind).

Comment: I completely agree with you. Set the `tabindex` through code. Advance when a number is pressed, return when backspace is pressed

Answer (score 0):

I think you can bind the textbox changes on the same event via the designer. Then you implement a function that finds the current tab index and sets the tab index +1 when a number is pressed. When backspace is pressed it does the opposite. As far as basic controls go i'm not aware of any existing for what you are looking for.